# C# 8.0 Using Declarations

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In C# 8.0 we can now use [using declarations in C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations). Are they really such a good idea? Consider this using statement:

```
private int SomeMethod()
{
    using (var t = new StreamWriter("somefile.txt"))
    {

    } // dispose of variable t

    // 100 lines of code
}
```

As soon as the closing brace is reached, the variable `t` is disposed of. With using declarations, the scenario is different:

```
private int SomeMethod()
{
    using var t = new StreamWriter("somefile.txt");

    // 100 lines of code
} // dispose of variable t
```

The variable `t` is only disposed at the end of the method. Using statements seem more efficient to me, because you only keep the object "alive" for as long as you need it.

Comment: They're good if you don't have 100 lines of code there, or you do but you don't care that `t` is only disposed after they're executed.

Comment: You should only convert a using statement to a using declaration if the statement ends just before the end of the scope it is in.  If you have code after it where you don't need the object then stick with a using statement.

Comment: It depends on the circumstance. If you're going to wrap an entire scope in a `using` statement, then sure it's a good idea to use a using deceleration. If you only need it for a _section_ of your scope then use a traditional `using` statement.

Comment: So a using declaration would be best suited at the end of a long method (if possible)?

Comment: @MarkDubovsky IMHO use what's best for readability... `the compiler generates the call to Dispose() no matter the case`. My rule is if I have a few lines of code I'll use the one liner anything more that would need to be wrapped up, then of course the other.

Comment: @MarkDubovsky The usefulness of having a using deceleration is to prevent an unnecessary indentation in your code if the _entire scope_ depends upon that using deceleration. By that logic a using deceleration is more useful at the _start_ of a scope (if that entire scope depends upon that object not being disposed) than it is at the _end_ of a scope.

Comment: It will be disposed at the end of the *scope* it was declared in. So for instance if you put the using statement inside a loop body, it will be disposed at the end of that body. But yes, all you noticed about "end of the method" is true if that is the scope. If you can dispose of it earlier, do so. The new syntax is a simplified syntax for when the scope is also the lifetime of the object (in terms of dispose). It is not meant as a replacement for `using (...) { ... }`. However, perhaps the method would be a candidate for refactoring anyway?

Comment: The *real* question you should probably ask yourself in this case is whether methods with 100 lines of code are such a good idea! With short, focused methods ways to reduce otherwise uninformative nesting become much more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

The answers can be as many as different scenarios.

In your case for example it could either be:

1. The function is big enough that it do would make sense to split. Remember that in modern programming with unit testing in mind, the units must be sufficiently small and the functions to do specific things.
2. The 100 lines will end in quite quickly. If that's the case, then it's ok to use the new more readable definition.
3. The same resources are needed a few lines below. Then why not use the same instance and then dispose?
4. In the rest of the lines, something else happens that takes time. Then it does not make sense to keep an item non-disposed (like a Stream) and the old way should be used.

The list could go on. There is no one solution fits all example but in most cases I think the first applies.